# MySQL to JSON Encode Error / No Results

Tags: php, mysql, json, encode

I know this type of question has been asked a couple of times but my problem is a little bit different and I can't figure out of to fix this. I've checked other similar questions but couldn't find a solution since everything seems correct.

I have a database table named *KalkanliMekanlar* and it has 3 tables inside it. Right now, I want to encode the contents of *Mekanlar* table. It has 5 columns and 22 rows inside it.

When I run the following PHP code, I see no result. I'd be grateful if you can help me with this.

I don't know if it helps but my server is on digitalocean.

Thank you very much for your help!

PHP Code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Mekanlar";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($connection));

$emparray[] = array();

while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $emparray[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($emparray);

mysqli_close($connection);
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Any errors in your error log?

Comment: Can you echo the number of rows being returned after result? http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php

Comment: nothing wrong with the code as is. check how many rows were returned: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php. but even if the query returned nothing, you should get AT LEAST `[]` as the output, due to json_encoding an empty array.

Comment: I get 22 rows as result

Comment: And there are no new errors regarding this issue on the error log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after doing @RhinoDevel's suggestion, also do this

```
while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
     array_push($emparray,$row);
}
```

EDIT : following comments from Rhino,

```
    $array[] = array ();
    for ($i = 0 ; $i < 5 ; $i++) {
        $array[] = $i;
    }
    $logger->info("OP : " . json_encode($array));
    $array = array ();
    for ($i = 0 ; $i < 5 ; $i++) {
        $array[] = $i;
    }
    $logger->info("RD : " . json_encode($array));

    $array = array ();
    for ($i = 0 ; $i < 5 ; $i++) {
        array_push($array , $i);
    }
    $logger->info("YL : " . json_encode($array));
```

yields :

```
2015-07-17T06:59:42-04:00 TestPatient.api           INFO  OP : [[],0,1,2,3,4]
2015-07-17T06:59:42-04:00 TestPatient.api           INFO  RD : [0,1,2,3,4]
2015-07-17T06:59:42-04:00 TestPatient.api           INFO  YL : [0,1,2,3,4]
```

Comment: This should make no difference to using the brackets (at least since PHP 4), see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php

Comment: @RhinoDevel ure right, cant downvote my own answer but i can +1 yours.

Answer (score 2):

Replace this:

```
$emparray[] = array();
```

with that:

```
$emparray = array();
```